# Understanding some banking domain-specific examples from Eric Evans's DDD book

Tags: java, c#, uml, domain-driven-design

Unfortunately, I can't overcome difficulties while I am trying to understand banking specific examples in that book. And that really slows my speed down. May be somebody can help me.

It seems to me, authors is not explaining that domain specific examples well. At first, he shows  us some model diagram which is relatively easy. And then some dialog with domain expert, and then BOOM, new words inside model which I am seeing for the first time. And I can't understand. And even don't know whether I need to understand it or not. For example, from Chapter 9, that model:

[image]

Becomes to this:

[image]

What the heck is `DailyCompound`, what is `Accrual Schedule`.

What I am missing? May be I have to learn banking domain? To be honest, I know what the author wants to explain us and I get all advantages of that knowledge crunching, whick makes some hidden models obvious. But, I want to fully understand why model become so?

Comment: I guess the number of guys with banking background is quite low here. To me it's reverse Chinese.

Comment: For the fun of it I googled for "accrual". Turned out it's explained with even more words I never heard of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my take on this:

The first picture shows a very Service-oriented model where the "Calculators" are more or less technical service. I think the author wanted to show that this is a model created by a developer rather than a domain expert.

If now the developer would ask a banking expert the following question: "How do you guys calculate your fees to bill the customers?" the conversation could go like this:

- A: "Well that depends on the method used for the asset in question"
- Q: "So there are `Asset`s... and what kind of methods?"
- A: "Well, we employ two kinds of `Accrural Schedule`s. `Monthly` and `Daily`. Daily sums up all fees based on the respective interest rate of that day. whereas monthly is more like a lump sum for that month"
- Q: "And how would you know which fees to sum up at the time of calculation?"
- A: "We keep a record or history of all past `Income Accrual`s and go from there. So we always know the `lastAccrualDate`. Oh, and we keep a record of the `Payment`s as well, if that helps"

I am not a banking expert myself, details may be inaccurate here. But the latter model *could* actually stem from a conversation with the domain experts. I think this is the point the author wants to make